# IE11 - modifier letter left/right arrowhead

Tags: html, utf-8, fonts, character-encoding, internet-explorer-11

In some misguided effort to avoid script injection we have decided to convert all "less/greater than"-signs to "left/right arrow"-modifier letters.

Using IE11 in development everything is fine and dandy. However, when deployed to PROD these modifier letters are displayed as boxes. PROD is accessed using other computers but as far as I can tell it's the same version of IE11 and all relevant settings are the same between the computers. All users see boxes instead of modifier letters - also on other pages, example:

```
<<<< - less than
>>>> - greater than
˂˂˂˂ - modifier letter left arrowhead
˃˃˃˃ - modifier letter right arrowhead
```

is displayed as:

[image: Example]

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Further investigation, we are using a a font that is not present on dev machines, but on prod machines. This font does not seem to contain the modifier letters.

However, when I type these letters into Word and change into our font it displays correctly although the two types of characters aren't the exact same they are close enough, and the non-supported characters seem to fallback to some system font. Why does this not happen in the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems the above characters are not supported by either of the fonts in our font-family stack, i.e:

```
* { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; }
```

From what I can gather, this means the browser falls back to a system level font for the unrecognized characters. Apparently, it seems this fallback can differ between machines. My solution was to add a third fallback font that I knew contained the character, like so:

```
* { font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, monospace; }
```